# Both Thunderbird and emacs throw d-bus errors unless sudoed (X OK!)

Tags: thunderbird, emacs, dbus

I have a newly installed Ubuntu system to which I have added LAMP and emacs.

Everything appears to be working with the exception of emacs and Thunderbird both throw similar errors:

#### Thunderbird

```
WARNING: Application calling GLX 1.3 function "glXCreatePixmap" when GLX 1.3 is not supported!  This is an application bug!
failed to create drawable

(thunderbird-bin:4822): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-UZuTljsm2d: Connection refused
GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running

(thunderbird-bin:4822): libunity-CRITICAL **: unity-launcher.vala:154: Unable to connect to session bus: Error connecting: Connection refused

libindicate-ERROR **: Unable to get session bus: Error connecting: Connection refused
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

#### Emacs

```
(emacs:4860): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-W2DTQUWcsw: Connection refused
GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running

(emacs:4860): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-jP1MzFGVET: Connection refused
```

However emacs will work if I sudo it and dbus is running, see below:

```
  750 ?        Ss     0:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork --activation=upstart
 1302 ?        Ss     0:00 //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 8 --print-address 10 --session
 1893 pts/0    S      0:00 dbus-launch --autolaunch 5083cb999a9b950abece203100000005 --binary-syntax --close-stderr
 1894 ?        Ss     0:00 //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 –session
```

Has anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by installing dbus-x11.

```
sudo apt-get install dbus-x11
```

Comment: This didn't help me. Are other actions required to make it work?

Comment: Same as @Hack Saw. Actually, dbus-x11 was already installed. Observed on Xubuntu 15.04 .